# Selectivity in tosylation of sulphur and oxygen

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilicity

#### Problem

> [image]

#### Answer

> **C**

#### Question

The first step involves a nucleophilic substitution on the sulphur atom of the tosyl group. I reasoned that in the cyclohexane substrate, the sulphur atom (thiol group) will be more nucleophilic than the oxygen atom (alcohol group) due its larger size, higher polarizability and less solvation. Accordingly I proceeded by the following mechanism -

[image]

which gives **D** as the answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There are not many examples of alkyl thiols reacting with tosyl chloride. There's this http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p1016 but it is not very similar. It seems that tosyl chloride is selctive for alcohols over thiols.

Comment: I was thinking the same @Waylander - I've seen plenty of questions where OH is converted to OTs, almost always for making it a leaving group, but it was the first time there was this possibility of sulphur acting as nucleophile.

Comment: I cannot recall using or seeing -S-Ts used as a leaving group

Comment: If -S-Ts is formed, it may act as tosylating functionality toward -OH but poorer than TsCl..